# Update Excel Data with Password in PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell, passwords

I need open a excel file with password, update, save and close.

I try this code, but i havent sucessed.

Anyone Can help me?

```
#Set the file path (can be a network location)
$filePath = "C:\Users\12291\Desktop\Excel\Base Vendas 2020_NOVA.xlsx"

#Create the Excel Object
$excelObj = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

#Make Excel visible. Set to $false if you want this done in the background
$excelObj.Visible = $true
$updatelinks = 3D



#Open the workbook
$workBook = $excelObj.Workbooks.Open($filePath, $updatelinks,$false, 0,5 , "vendas")

#Focus on the top row of the "Data" worksheet
#Note: This is only for visibility, it does not affect the data refresh
#$workSheet = $workBook.Sheets.Item("Data")
#$workSheet.Select()

#Refresh all data in this workbook
$workBook.RefreshAll()

#Save any changes done by the refresh
$workBook.Save()

#Uncomment this line if you want Excel to close on its own
#$excelObj.Quit()
```

Comment: There's Query in this file.

Comment: There's a typo: `$updatelinks = 3D` --> `$updatelinks = 3`